# Dask's custom graph description

Tags: dask

I'm Using dask custom graph

How can i print the graph defeintion

For example consider this grpah

```
dsk = {'load-1': (load, 'myfile.a.data'),
       'load-2': (load, 'myfile.b.data'),
       'load-3': (load, 'myfile.c.data'),
       'clean-1': (clean, 'load-1'),
       'clean-2': (clean, 'load-2'),
       'clean-3': (clean, 'load-3'),
       'analyze': (analyze, ['clean-%d' % i for i in [1, 2, 3]]),
       'store': (store, 'analyze')}
```

i would like to print out the above description by calling someting like

```
print dsk
```

i know about dot_graph(dask,'image.png')
but i would like to get a textual description

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now and the Pyhton pretty printer will do a decent job.  The biggest difference is that it will print functions like `<function sum>` rather than `sum`, which is a bit unpleasant.  It seems reasonable for dask to include a special pretty print function.  Perhaps you could [raise an issue](https://github.com/blaze/dask/issues/new)?

Comment: Your example makes it look easy but it is quite tricky to determine which name(s) a Python object is bound to in the current scope: walk the frame stack, get vars for outer scope, match results of id().

Comment: Yeah, that's clearly quite difficult.  Relying on function metadata, like the `func.__name__` attribute is often sufficient in the common case.